# Orangish-coloured insect living in wood chips

Tags: entomology, species-distribution

Can anyone Identify this organism?[image: about 4"long]

I dug it up in a pile of 5 year old wood chips in Cleveland, Tennessee, United States. It is about 4 inches long.

Answer (score 11):

That is the pupa of a unicorn beetle, *Dynastes tityus*. https://arthurevans.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/453/